# In openerp, how to access field value of form via wizard

Tags: odoo, wizard, invoices

This might be silly but i don't have idea.

While we go to Accounting -> Customers -> Customer Invoices(model: account.invoice) there is a field 'Total'(amount_total).

I have added a boolean field in account.voucher.

```
 'test': fields.boolean('Test'),
```

Now in wizard(Pay Invoice) which opens on click of button 'Register payment'. I want to make this field visible or unvisible based on value of 'Total'. If the value we fill in 'Paid Amount'(amount) is less than 'Total' then 'test' field should be visible  else invisible.

How can i make it possible?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the `account_voucher-> invoice.py` file there is a method named `invoice_pay_customer`.

this is the method is called when the you click on the Register Payment button(enable the debug mode), you just need to update the context value, you just need to override this method like,

```
def invoice_pay_customer(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    vals = super(invoice, self).invoice_pay_customer(cr, uid, ids, context=None)
    inv = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
    vals.get('context').update({"default_amount": inv.amount_total})
    return vals
```

it will set the amount in the popup.

Answer (score -1):

as far i understand after read your question is that you want value of total amount in invoice form ok?

and based on this you want to hide some fields?

for the you can do one things,

add one field total in wizard, which contain value of invoice total,

to get value of the invoice total

overwrite the default_get method

```
def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
```

in this metho you will get active_id or active_ids of current invoice from this actiove id you will get invoice total field value and set in wizard total value

hope this help

Comment: Thanx for your reply. Is there something that i can get value directly??????? I mean with less .py changes.

Comment: then do as atul wrote

Comment: or in account_voucher module in def invoice_pay_customer(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None): in context add invoice total value and from context you able to get invoice total value